# textfield validations using jquery

Tags: jquery

In one textbox users are only allowed to enter numeric values less than 99.99.How to set this validation using jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this jQuery Validation Plugin

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation

```
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    field: {
      required: true,
      max: 99.99
    }
  }
});
```